# Origin and use of an identity of formal power series: $\det(1 - \psi T) = \exp \left(-\sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \text{Tr}(\psi^{s})T^{s}/s\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, power-series, determinant, p-adic-number-theory

The following is a **historical question**, but first some **background**:

Let $\psi$ be a linear operator from a vector space to itself. The following two expressions, viewed as formal power series, can be shown to be equal (even for an infinite dimensional vector space):

$$
\det(1 - \psi T) = \exp \left(-\sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \text{Tr}(\psi^{s})T^{s}/s\right)
$$

Here is a simple example using the associated matrix in the finite dimensional case:

[image]

For more on this topic (and how to ensure the definitions make sense for infinite dimensional vector spaces) see: N. Koblitz, *p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions*, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1984.

In particular, see Koblitz's book for how ($p$-adic versions of) this identity can be used in Bernard Dwork's proof of the rationality of the zeta function (resolving the first of the Weil Conjectures).

I would welcome any insight as to how one thinks up, observes, or conjectures such an identity in the first place, but my **question** is: what is the origin of this identity and where else has it appeared (perhaps in a somewhat modified form)?

Comment: Its discussed on the wikipedia page for the determinant. It can be viewed as a form of the identity $\exp(\mathrm{tr}(M))=\det\exp(M)$.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil If you can write up something formal showing why this is the case, I will accept it as an answer. (Unless others can shed more light on where else this identity shows up and what its history is.)

Comment: Since you ask the question in relation to its use in Dwork's proof of the first Weil conjectures... I think this kind of identity was known to Weil, who first defined the zeta-function of a variety in fairly general terms. You might look at his 1949 paper where he stated his conjectures, just to see if it provides some inspiration for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The development of this operator identity can be traced back till the very beginning of the 20th century.

I think the paper *[On the numerical evaluation of Fredholm determinants](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.2543v2.pdf)* from *Folkmar Bornemann (2008)* could be useful for you. Bornemann presents in *Section 3:  Definition and Properties of Fredholm and Operator Determinants* of this paper *four different representations* of your stated operator identity. He writes:

> For a trace class operator $A \in \mathcal{J}_1(\mathcal{H})$ there are several equivalent constructions that all define one and the same *entire* function
>   \begin{align*}
> d(z)=\text{det}(I+zA)\qquad(z\in\mathbb{R})
> \end{align*}
>   in fact, each construction has been chosen at least once, in different places of the literature, as the basic definition of the operator determinant:

$1.)$ *Gohberg and Krein ($1969$, p. $157$)* define the determinant by the locally uniformly convergent (infinite) product
\begin{align*}
\text{det}(I+zA)=\prod_{n=1}^{N(A)}(1+z\lambda_n(A))
\end{align*}
which possesses zeros exactly at $z_n=-1/\lambda_n(A)$, counting multiplicity.

$2.)$ *Gohberg et al. ($1990$, p. $115$)* define the determinant as follows. Given any sequence of finite rank operators $A_n$ with $A_n\rightarrow A$ converging in trace class norm, the sequence of finite dimensional determinants
\begin{align*}
\text{det}\left(I+zA_n\upharpoonright_{\text{ran}(A_n)}\right)
\end{align*}
(which are polynomials in z) converges locally uniform to $\text{det}(I+zA)$, independently of the choice of the sequence $A_n$. The existence of at least one such sequence follows from the singular value representation at $(2.1)$.

> $3.)$ *Dunford and Schwartz ($1963$, p. $1029$)* define the determinant by what is often called Plemelj’s formula
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{det}(I+zA)=\exp(\text{tr}\ \text{log}(I+zA))=\exp\left(-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-z)^n}{n}\text{tr}A^n\right)
> \end{align*}
>   which converges for $|z|<1/|\lambda_1(A)|$ and can analytically be continued as an entire function to all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

$4.)$ *Grothendieck ($1956$, p. $347$) and Simon ($1977$, p. $254$)* define the determinant most elegantly with a little exterior algebra (Greub $1967$). With $\bigwedge^n(A)\in\mathcal(J)_1\left(\bigwedge^n(\mathcal{H})\right)$ being the $n^\text{th}$ exterior product of $A$, the power series
\begin{align*}
\text{det}(I+zA)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n\text{tr}\bigwedge^n(A)
\end{align*}
converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Note that $\text{tr}\bigwedge^{n}(A)=\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_n}\lambda_{i_1}(A)\cdots\lambda_{i_n}(A)$ is just the $n^\text{th}$ symmetric function of the eigenvalues of $A$.

> *Proofs of the equivalence can be found in (Gohberg et al. $2000$, Chap. $2$) and (Simon $2005$, Chap. $3$).*

---

In a footnote for $3.)$ above, Bornemann provides additional information to the *Plemelj Formula*, namely:

> *Plemelj ($1904$, Eq. $(62)$)* had given a corresponding form of the Fredholm determinant for integral operators. However, it can already be found in *Fredholm ($1903$, p. $384$)*.

So, the formula seems to go back till Fredholm $1903$. I suppose according to some references I've found, it's the following paper:
*I. Fredholm*, *Sur une classe d`équation fonctionelle*, Acta Math. $27, 365-390 (1903)$.

Comment: @Benjamin Dickman: Thanks for the bounty. Since you put the question long time ago, its really good to see the answer pleases you! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Using $\det\exp=\exp\mathrm{tr}$, we have
$$
  \det(I-tA) = \det \exp\log(I-tA) = \exp\mathrm{tr}\log(I-tA)
$$
and as 
$$
  \log(I-tA) = -\sum_{k\ge1} \frac1k t^k A^k,
$$
we have
$$
  \exp\mathrm{tr}\log(I-tA) 
  = \exp\left( -\sum_{k\ge1} \frac1k t^k \mathrm{tr}(A^k)\right)
$$
This shows that your identity is a form of the $\det\exp$ identity.

The question about the origins is interesting and I do not have much to say (which was why I restricted myself to a comment in the first place). For complex matrices it is very easy to prove that $\det\exp(A)=\exp\mathrm{tr}(A)$, which might explain why I have never seen a name attached to it.

I have seen it used in connection with Lie groups (to prove that sl is the Lie algebra of SL), and (in forms like what you stated) in work on enumeration.

Comment: I'm sorry, how can we be sure that $I-tA$ admits a logarithm, for a generic $A$?

Comment: @Yecabel: it exists as a (formal) power series, which is all we need.

Comment: Right, thank you! And for saying that the trace of a series is the series of the traces we are using the continuity of the map "trace"?

Comment: @Yecabel: $\log(I-tA)^{-1}$ is a matrix, so you compute the trace in the usual way.

Comment: I am sorry for these (maybe silly questions), but I have some doubt. I think that the identity $\det\exp=\exp\text{trace}$ is true for matrices on every field, but if $\log(I-tA)$ is just a formal power series, I am not sure that the identity still remains true... And also it is not clear to me that taking the trace of a series we can just bring the trace inside as you did... Ok, trace is continuous if we start from finite dimensional v. spaces, but here we are computing the trace of a formal power series...

Comment: @Yecabel: You are working in the ring of power series in $T$, with coefficients matrices over a commutative ring of characteristic zero. Continuity has nothing to do with it, unless you are using the topology where two series in $T$ are close if their difference is divisible by a high power of $T$.